# Word Frequency Counter issue with logic java

Tags: java

I am building a basic word frequency counter. The code is listed below:

```
public static List<Frequency> computeWordFrequencies(List<String> words) 
{
    List<Frequency> list_of_frequency = new ArrayList<Frequency>();
    List<String> list_of_words = words;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<list_of_words.size(); i++)
    {

        String current_word = list_of_words.get(i);
        boolean added = false;
        if(list_of_frequency.size() == 0)
        {
            list_of_frequency.add(new Frequency(current_word, 1));
            System.out.println("added " + current_word);
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("Current word: " + current_word);
            System.out.println("Current Frequency: " + list_of_frequency.get(j).getText());
            if(list_of_frequency.contains(current_word))
            {
                list_of_frequency.get(j).incrementFrequency();
                System.out.println("found... incremented " + list_of_frequency.get(j).getText() + " frequency");
                added = true;
            }
            else
            {
                list_of_frequency.add(new Frequency(current_word, 1));
                System.out.println("added " + current_word);
                added = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output I am getting is:

```
added I
Current word: am
Current Frequency: I
added am
Current word: very
Current Frequency: I
added very
Current word: good
Current Frequency: I
added good
Current word: at
Current Frequency: I
added at
Current word: being
Current Frequency: I
added being
Current word: good
Current Frequency: I
added good
Total item count: 7
Unique item count: 7
I:1
am:1
very:1
good:1
at:1
being:1
good:1
```

So I need a for loop to loop through the "list_of_frequency" but if I do that I run into other problems such as adding words repetitively. Is my logic right here and would there be a better way going about this project?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code formatting can be improved.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting. I was trying to fix that.

Comment: If this is a basic exercise, I suggest you just use a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the word and the frequency the number of times this word appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this using [frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) method of `Collections` class

here is a sample:

```
public void wordFreq(){
String text = "hello bye hello a bb a bye hello";

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));

        Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String> (list);
        for (String word : uniqueWords) {
            System.out.println(word + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, word));
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this should be the top answer, simple and nice.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating things.

You only need a few lines:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getFrequencies(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : words) {
        Integer i = freq.get(word);
        freq.put(word, i == null ? 1 : i + 1);
    }
    return freq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside else part.
What you should do is

1. in a loop check if the word is already in the list
2. If part 1 is true just increment its frequency
3. else put it in the list with frequency 1

   ```
   for(j = 0; j < list_of_frequency.size; j++)
      if(list_of_frequency.get(i).getText().equals(current_word))
         list_of_frequency.get(i).frequency++; // increment frequency 
                                 //if word is already encountered before
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think to run faster you should use another algorithm starting by sorting the List:

```
  1) sort your list of string (cf. java.util.Collections.sort())
  2) in pseudo code :
 iterate your sorted list
 current_word = word of current iteration
 if it's a new word (! current_word.equals( oldWord) )
 counter = 1
 if (current_word.equals( oldWord)) {
    counter++
     store current_word in variable oldWord 
 }
 when the word change create your Frequency(oldWord, counter) and add to the list of frequencies
```

So you don't need to check your frequency list every time and you insert one time for one word, it's quicker.

Since all entries of list list_of_frequency are unique words you could also use a Set instead of a list for list_of_frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method with this. You'll get a lot better performance by using a map while analyzing your data.

```
public static List<Frequency> computeWordFrequencies(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String word : words) {
        Integer current = counts.get(word);
        if(current != null) {
            counts.put(word, current+1);
        }
        else counts.put(word, 1);
    }

    // Then, if you really need that list of Frequency
    List<Frequency> list_of_frequency = new ArrayList<Frequency>();

    for(String s : counts.keySet()) {
        list_of_frequency.add(new Frequency(s, counts.get(s)));
    }

    return list_of_frequency;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. multiple comments have told me to use Hashmap. My only question when I implemented the code is,  why does it give me a null pointer exception when its "int current = ..." and fixes the error when its "Integer currrent =..."? And if "Integer" and "int" are not the same (based on my understanding, one of them is an object) then why does Frequency(string, int) accepts Frequency(string, Integer)?

Comment: That's because `Integer` is an object (which allows a `null` value), and `int` in a primitive, which cannot be `null`. The compiler automates the casting between `int` and `Integer` but if you try to put a null value in an `int`, you will get that error. By using `Integer`, you tell the compiler not to cast to `int` so you can make sure it's not `null`. I hope I didn't confuse you even more...

Comment: Ok I get it better now. that makes sense; explains why its `null` in the if-statement rather than `0`

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed like this :

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "qux", "foo");

Map<String, AtomicInteger> frequencyMap = new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
for (String word : words)
{
    AtomicInteger freq = frequencyMap.get(word);
    if (freq == null) {
        frequencyMap.put(word, new AtomicInteger(1));
    }
    else
    {
        freq.incrementAndGet();
    }
}

for (String word : frequencyMap.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(word + " :" + frequencyMap.get(word));
}
```

By using [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) you can easily increment your frequency counter.